# Publishing Json Deserialisation errors using DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer doesn't publish the original payload

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am using Spring Boot 2.3.1 and want to publish records that could not be deserialized using the DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.

Everything looks fine, except that the original payload isn't written to the DLT topic. Instead I see it Base64 encoded.

In a different posting I have read that this is caused by the JsonSerializer that is used in the Kafkatemplate, so I tried using a different template. But now I get an SerializationException:

`org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class [B to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.BytesSerializer specified in value.serializer`

A similar exception occurs when using the StringSerializer.

My code looks like this:

```
    @Autowired
    private KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    private ProducerFactory<String, String> pf() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties());
    }

    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> stringTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(pf(), Collections.singletonMap(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler() {

        SeekToCurrentErrorHandler eh = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(stringTemplate()));
        eh.setLogLevel(Level.WARN);
        return eh;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it just 5 minutes later.

I had to use the `ByteArraySerializer` instead.